# Free to paid app transition

Tags: android

So I am ready to launch a paid version of one of my apps and I obviously have one of two options.

1. Have the common business logic as a library and then have two versions of views (one for free and one for paid - having different package names)
2. Unlocker app to unlock some of the paid features from a free app.

My concern here is that if I go with option 1, I will have to have two layouts for each user-screen that I have. I am using admob in my free app, and will continue to do so in the next version of the free app too. Since there is an ad bar under every screen, my layout elements , eg, a listview that occupies the entire screen has bottomMargin set to the height of the ad-bar. So this necessitates two layouts (or does it??)

If I go with option 2, I dont know what is the best way to do that as well. I mean do I have a SqliteDB which gets overwritten by the paid app or something??

I also want to have a code base that is easily maintainable in atleast the forceable future.

And last but not least, how do I ensure that a person who has the paid version installed is actually the person who has bought the app, not some one who has downloaded my apk from the net or something!

Comment: Actually i am asking you question about uploading paid application on google market. is it necessary that account to be  not opened from india, i heard that only free application are uploaded. see the link https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/android-market/feature-requests--suggestions/k4kae3g5Eeg are you able to upload paid application from india ?

Comment: I think I will be asking one of my friends from US to do it for me. I know, it sucks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll ignore everything else but this:

> Since there is an ad bar under every screen, my layout elements , eg, a listview that occupies the entire screen has bottomMargin set to the height of the ad-bar. So this necessitates two layouts (or does it??)

No. Remove the margin and, if using a RelativeLayout as the parent ensure that the ListView has the `android:layout_above` property set and if the ad isn't needed set the ad bar visibility to `Gone` or, if using a LinearLayout as the parent simply set the ad visibility to `Gone`.

Comment: Will this ensure that the bottom margins for the layout elements be set properly?? I mean that the ad will not hide some of my content?

Comment: It depends on the rest of your layout. If you're using a FrameLayout as the parent of the ListView and ad bar then no (and you should likely redesign it anyway). If you're using a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout then yes.

Comment: I am using Relative layouts. Thanks a ton! But unfortunately, since its not an answer to the entire question, all I can do is an upvote! Gratitude!

Comment: Well, since I have had no other answers for this, I am marking yours as the correct answer!